# How to replicate a sheet using VBA Macro (not copy) replicate

Tags: excel, vba

How would I replicate a sheet using VBA Macro but not use the VBA copy method?

So I want Sheet2 to look exactly like Sheet1 after.

I am new to VBA Macros so please guide me.

Comment: What's wrong with copy? `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)`

Comment: @SiddharthRout I don't want to use copy. can you please tell me another way?

Comment: Yes there is another way as well but can you confirm why don't you want to use `.Copy`. I am actually intrigued.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I want to see which way works better for me. Please show me the other way.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you answer Sid's question above? (i.e., why can you not use copy). I am asking because, `copy` is designed exactly for that purpose, and would like to know what is that it does not capture and in which context. Thanks!

Comment: quick question. do you want to make the copy in the same workbook or in another existing workbook or a new workbook?

Comment: Ok then see my answer. Also see the recent edit that I made. You may have to refresh the page to see it.

Comment: One difference between the .copy method and the _.sheets.add,  cells.copy_ method is the latter won't copy any worksheet macros that might be stored with the source worksheet. That could be an important difference if you are concerned that the source sheets might have _malicious_, or just annoying embedded macros.  OTOH, if you want to keep the worksheet embedded macros, you _have_ to use .copy. At least that's true with _my_ Trust Center settings.

Comment: It looks like if you check the box by _Trust access to the VBA project object model_, you can write macros from a macro. Maybe even copy or delete them from worksheets or modules,  I don't think a user would feel comfortable about that. Anyone tried it? I have not, do not plan to anytime soon. Although... K^J

Answer (score 7):

Here are couple of ways

**WAY 1 Best way to do it**

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy _
After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count)
```

**Way 2**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wsToCopy As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet

    On Error GoTo Whoa:

    Set wsToCopy = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

    wsNew.Name = "Copy of " & wsToCopy.Name

    wsToCopy.Cells.Copy wsNew.Cells

    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

**NOTE:**

In case you are using `Excel 2003`, then **WAY 2** might be the best way depending on the data. Please [SEE THIS](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213548)

Comment: this still using copy method