# Sub procedure for importing the sheets it's substandar

Tags: vba, excel

I get this code to work for a time but the last couple of days it has not been working. from active workbook1 its suppose to import the sheets to Thisworkbook2:

```
Sub ImportallWBsh()

    'https://michaelaustinfu.files.wordpress.com/2013/03/excel-vba-for-dummies-3rd-edition.pdf, Page 245
    Dim Finfo As String
    Dim FilterIndex As Integer
    Dim Title As String
    Dim Filename As Variant
    Dim wb As Workbook


    'Setup the list of file filters
    Finfo = "Excel Files (*.xlsx),*xlsx,"

    'Display *.* by default
    FilterIndex = 1

    'Set the dialog box caption
    Title = "Select a File to Import"

    'Get the Filename
    Filename = Application.GetOpenFilename(Finfo, _
        FilterIndex, Title)

    'Handle return info from dialog box
    If Filename = False Then
        MsgBox "No file was selected."
    Else
        MsgBox "You selected " & Filename
    End If

    On Error Resume Next

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename)



    FilenameWorkbook.Sheets.Copy _
        After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

     wb.Close True

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select

End Sub
```

Do you know what might be wrong about it.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a couple issues going on...

You are using `Set` incorrectly.  `GetOpenFileName` returns a string.  `Workbooks.Open` returns an object.  Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3884929/8112776) out.  The first section of your could read:

```
s = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Set Wb1 = Workbooks.Open (s)
```

You're also opening workbook `s` twice, plus you create object `objexcel` which creates a new instance of Excel, but you don't close it with `Set objexcel = Nothing`, so each time you run the code, you'll have another copy of Excel open in the background.

(Close Excel, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>DEL</kbd> to check your Task Manager and I bet you'll see what I mean!)

To start with I suggest you try [this search](https://www.google.ca/search?q=excel%20vba%20copy%20worksheets%20from%20another%20workbook), which will show a number of solutions to the same question that have worked for others, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6863940/how-to-copy-sheets-to-another-workbook-using-vba) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246465/how-to-copy-only-a-single-worksheet-to-another-workbook-using-vba).

Comment: I got the code to work after a few days reading your recommended search and some other material. I Really appreciated Thank you. Now  I would like to show you How the code looks like now for additional insights or suggestions Do I edit my post in here or is there any other way I could post my code here so  you could look at it? Thank you

Comment: You're welcome!  ummmm good question.  As you probably already know, some people here are very picky about posting certain ways.  (Today someone else's question was removed because **I** posted a picture as an Answer when it was really just to ask for clarification! (I feel bad for the question-asker!)  But yes I'd like to see your code.  I think it will be okay if you **Edit** your original question, and at the **end** of it put : "Update: " with a short explanation and your code.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the job for you.

```
Sub Basic_Example_1()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, Fnum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "C:\Users\Ron\test"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        Fnum = Fnum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
        MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If Fnum > 0 Then
        For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next

                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:C1")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    'if SourceRange use all columns then skip this file
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "Sorry there are not enough rows in the sheet"
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        'Copy the file name in column A
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(Fnum)
                        End With

                        'Set the destrange
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        'we copy the values from the sourceRange to the destrange
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If

        Next Fnum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm

Answer (score 0):

The correct line code needs to be:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Copy _
        After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Hoja3")
```

So the code work properly. Thank you