# Need assistance updating macro to copy and save worksheet instead of entire workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following macro that loops through a list of clients and saves individual workbooks for each client in a specific file location. The issue that is going over my head is I want to only save one particular worksheet in the workbook per client and not all of the tabs from the workbook.

Here is the entire macro:

```
Sub ClientDataRefresh()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")

    Dim dvCell As Range
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim i As Long

     'Cell that has data validation
    Set dvCell = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Range("C5")
     'Determine where validation comes from
    Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)

    i = 1
     'Begin loop
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     For Each c In inputRange
     dvCell = c.Value
     ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Range("A1:O10").Columns.AutoFit

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template")
    LR = .Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
    10: If .Cells(LR, 7) = "" Then LR = LR - 1: GoTo 10
    .PageSetup.PrintArea = "$A$1:$I$" & LR
    End With

     thisDate = Replace(Date, "/", "-")
     thisName = Sheets("Template").Range("H7").Text
     filePath = "C:\Users\nalanis\Dropbox (Decipher Dev)\Analytics\Sales\"
     Application.DisplayAlerts = False
     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Select
     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Copy
     ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").SaveAs Filename:=filePath & thisName & " " & "Usage Report" & " "  & thisDate & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
     Application.DisplayAlerts = True
     ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Next c

    End With


End Sub
```

I have tried looking and applying different potential solutions but no such luck.

Comment: Is the worksheet you want to save same for all clients or does it change? Eg. Is it always "Template" tab? Can you delete all the other tabs just before saving?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246465/how-to-copy-only-a-single-worksheet-to-another-workbook-using-vba). After you've created a new workbook with `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Copy`, you don't reference that new workbook when trying to save it - you're still referencing `ThisWorkbook` when you want `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: Hi @Aneta, yes that is correct. It's always the template tab. The data changes for each client during each refresh but that is the tab I use.

Comment: Hey @BigBen so I made the following change: ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").SaveAs -> ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Template").Save As. What I see now is that the last client's data on my loop is being saved for all of my clients. I came across this yesterday and wasn't sure how to resolve it.

Comment: 1. You don't need `Worksheets("Template")`... - [Workbook.SaveAs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-saveas-method-excel). 2. Without your file in front of me, it's hard to say what's causing that issue.

Comment: @BigBen it would be great if I could provide it but I have a direct connect to SQL Server so it will fail as the macro is executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code i've used to save only 1 worksheet as a .csv file. Basically it removes every sheet other than the sheet I want ("Pending") and saves it as .csv, but then closes the original workbook without saving, as to not save with all the deletions I did.

```
Dim excelObject As Object
Dim objExcel As Object
Dim sheet As Object
Dim csvFile As String
xlFile = "C:\Users\PathName.xlsx"
csvFile = Left(xlFile, InStrRev(xlFile, ".")) & "csv"

'open excel file
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set excelObject = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\PathName.xlsx")
'Recognize the sheet we are looking to import
Set sheet = excelObject.Worksheets("Pending")
'suppresses dialog boxes when deleting worksheets
excelObject.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Dim wsName As String

'Delete all sheets except the one sheet we want
wsName = "Pending"

For Each Sh In excelObject.Worksheets
    If Sh.Name <> wsName Then
        Sh.Delete
    End If
Next Sh

'Save the file as a CSV but do not save the original workbook we edited
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs csvFile, FileFormat:=6, CreateBackup:=False
excelObject.Close

'Closes out of excel and removes it from the computer memory
objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: This definitely got me on the right path to figure out my issue. Thank you so much!