# Copy a sheet to a New workbook (of one sheet) without opening it

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to copy a sheet from ActiveWorkbook, to a **New** Created workbook. 
The New created workbook, will contains the copied sheet **ONLY**.

I also don't want it to open while copiying the sheet. I want to copy the sheet to the new created workbook silently.

If I do something like the following, the new created book is with 3 sheets, not one only, and it's opening while copiying. and also it's asking me if i want to saved it with Macro, while I only want to copy the sheet1, so no need for any macro with it, How to fix that to fits my needs ?

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\DestinationWb.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
```

Comment: Does `Sheet1` have VBA code-behind? If so, the *document module* (i.e. the corresponding VBA project component) is copied along with the Excel worksheet; if you need that code, the `FileFormat` you want is `xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`; that `51` is the underlying value for `xlOpenXMLWorkbook`. I suspect that might be why Excel is warning about saving it with macros in the first place.

Comment: nope it doesn't, it's just a sheet with text formatted with colors and date format in some cells etc...but not vba behind.

Comment: hmm. [BigBen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55153589/1188513) / skipping the warnings should "just work" then.

Comment: I will give it a test and let you know, thanks to both for trying to help

Comment: I will answer you tomorrow because the code is at work and I am not at home I don't have the workbook here. Anyway my idea is at the end of the treatement (i have many things to do, before the copy), I will ask the user, do you want to open the generated file, if he say yes, I open it and if he says no, i don't open it). if i want to open after I used the code of BigBen, what is the instruction to use ? so that I try all by once tomorrow ?

Comment: Why not keep it opened and prompt whether to close it instead? It's there already, no need to close it if you're going to re-open the same file...

Comment: because i want to copy, make some treatment and prompt after that not directly...and what I think is that I will make a button instead of prompt that allow the user to open the book if he wants, I am thinking about different scenario. That's why I want to know how to open it later ... but for the moment beeing I want to open it silently and to have the only 1 sheet copied to it, but if you know the code to open it after the creation for later use let me know please

Comment: `Worksheet.Copy` creates the new destination workbook and activates that workbook - there's nothing to open and if you copied a worksheet the destination workbook is going to be opened whether you want it or not... still makes no sense to close it only to prompt the user if they want to open it. You're fighting the side-effects of `Worksheet.Copy`, the very same ones that even allow you to close the created workbook...

Comment: I didn't say I want forcely to use the .copy, if there is any other way to copy a sheet to another workbook without opening it, I would like to try it, I didn't say I want to use the .copy, but that's the only command that I know to copy a sheet, that's why I am asking here if someone else has different ways

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I just tried the code of BigBen, the book opens for 1-2 seconds, then it's closed. if there is a better way other than that or other than the sheet.copy please let me know, and if there is no other way, at least tell me so that I will know that it's impossible to do what I want. thanks again for all your comments and support

Comment: See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.copy), and note that a `Workbook` object you can interact with using the Excel object model in VBA, can only ever exist as an element of the `Application.Workbooks` collection: if it's not "opened", it doesn't exist as far as VBA is concerned. You could conceivably use OpenXML to create the file from scratch without the Excel object model, but since you're using VBA and you're already hosted in Excel it makes little sense to do so, and massively complexifies what should be a fairly simple thing.

Answer (score 3):

The newly created workbook will have to be open - otherwise how would you save it? - but toggling `Application.ScreenUpdating` might facilitate the "silent" copy you're looking for. Toggling `Application.DisplayAlerts` will also suppress alerts as needed.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="C:\DestinationWb.xlsx", FileFormat:=51
ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it tomorrow from work and let you know because I don't have right now the workbook.

Comment: Hello, I just tried the code you provided, it still opens the book for about 1-2 seconds and close it. the user will clearly see that the book is opened. is there any other way, not forcely the sheet.copy or it's the only way to copy ?

Answer (score 3):

> Hello, I just tried the code you provided, it still opens the book for about 1-2 seconds and close it. the user will clearly see that the book is opened. is there any other way, not forcely the sheet.copy or it's the only way to copy ? – JustGreat 50 mins ago

The only way I can think of in such a scenario is to do the following.

**Logic**:

1. Use the `.SaveCopyAs` method to save a copy of the existing workbook. You can read more about `.SaveCopyAs` [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835014.aspx)
2. Create another instance of Excel and Hide it
3. Open the copy in that instance
4. Delete all sheets except the one which you want.
5. Save and Close and finally quit the Excel instance.

**Code**:

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim thisWb As Workbook

    '~~> New File Name
    Dim NewFile As String
    NewFile = "C:\Users\routs\Desktop\New folder\DestinationWb.xlsx"

    '~~> Sheets that you want to copy across
    Dim SheetToCopy As String
    SheetToCopy = "Sidd"

    Set thisWb = ThisWorkbook

    '~~> Save a copy of the current workbook to the new path
    thisWb.SaveCopyAs NewFile

    '~~> Create a new Excel instance and keep it hidden
    Dim tmpExcelApp As Object
    Dim ws As Object, thatWb As Object
    Set tmpExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    tmpExcelApp.Visible = False

    '~~> Open the copy file in hidden instance
    Set thatWb = tmpExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(NewFile)

    '~~> Delete all sheets except the one we copied
    tmpExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False
    For Each ws In thatWb.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> SheetToCopy Then ws.Delete
    Next ws
    tmpExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = True

    '~~> Save and close
    thatWb.Close (True)

    '~~> Quit Excel Instance
    tmpExcelApp.Quit

    MsgBox "Done"
End Sub
```

Comment: That would indeed to it. Quite the roundabout way to go and still not making any sense to then prompt whether to open the created workbook, but yeah saving a copy and then deleting all but the one needed sheet will at least appear to do what the OP intends to do. Might want to turn calculations off while deleting the sheets though; depending on what's in there this could get painful otherwise ;-)

Comment: I would have used OleDb  `Drop Table` to silently delete the worksheet instead of opening in new instance but unfortunately  OleDb  `Drop Table` doesn't delete the worksheet. Wish it did...

Comment: But then yes, OP has to take care if there are formula referring to other sheets. Can be easily handled in the new instance though :)

Comment: Works just fine for me, but when I try to open the copied file, Excel says it can't open because it is not valid or corrupted, even though I copied the exact same code. Any suggestions?

Comment: @krobelusmeetsyndra: Post a new question with the exact code that you are using. Feel free to add a reference to this quesiton as well.

Comment: I can't post any more questions on this account, but I've put it on a pastebin. [Here](https://pastebin.com/s9WzZ4EK) it is.