# How to copy and paste a sheet in vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm searching how i can copy the activesheet in vba , i'm wanting to paste it in another workbook ( which is closed ).

Normaly i tried this but it fails :

```
 Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\target.xlsx" 
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Workbooks("target.xlsx").Sheets(Workbooks("target.xlsx").Worksheets.Count)
```

Comment: You have to open the workbook first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to copy only a single worksheet to another workbook using vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246465/how-to-copy-only-a-single-worksheet-to-another-workbook-using-vba)

Comment: I have this error " l'indice n'appartient pas à la selection "

Comment: Is `Workbooks("Book1.xlsx")` open?

Comment: I tried this :     Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\target.xlsx"
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Workbooks("target.xlsx").Sheets(Workbooks("target.xlsx").Worksheets.Count)

Comment: Now i don't know how to close the workbook target.xlsx

Comment: @BigBen  yes it's opened !

Comment: [`Workbook.Close`](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.close).

Comment: @BigBen  this will close all the opened workbooks , i'm wanting to close just the target.xlsx

Comment: That is not true. Try it.

Comment: I try it. it closes all the opened workbooks after displaying a message !

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your revised code, thanks.

Comment: I'm wanting to copy and paste the activesheet at the end of another workbook but this is not working for me !

Comment: Please [edit] your question with your attempt to use `Workbook.Close`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Workbooks.Open` is a function. It returns a `Workbook` object reference, pointing to the `Workbook` object that was just opened.

> ```
> Workbooks.Open Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\target.xlsx"
> ```

You are discarding that reference.

Capture it!

```
Dim targetBook As Workbook
Set targetBook = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\target.xlsx")
```

Now instead of dereferencing that workbook from the `Workbooks` collection everytime you need it...

> ```
> ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Workbooks("target.xlsx").Sheets(Workbooks("target.xlsx").Worksheets.Count)
> ```

Simply use the object you've got:

```
ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=targetBook.Sheets(targetBook.Worksheets.Count)
```

And when you're done, invoke it's `Close` method to close it:

```
targetBook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Comment: Thank you a lot @Mathieu Guindon                                                                                 You solved the question.