# PasteSpecial causing macro to fail.. why?

Tags: vba, excel

The below Macro opens an external workbook, unhides a particular sheet and reads a couple of text values into variables, creates a new sheet in the current workbook based on those variable values, copies the contents of a worksheet in that workbook, then pastes it into the new one.

However, when I use `.Paste` it works fine, but doesn't retain the formatting and only pastes in the text.

If I try to correct this and use

```
.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
```

It fails.

Why is this?

```
Sub addsheet()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

filename = Sheets("Instructions").Range("C13").Value
report = "report.xlsx"
report_filepath = "\\xxx\xxx\xxx\report.xlsx"
Dim report_name As String

Workbooks.Open Filename:=(report_filepath)

    Windows(report).Activate
    Sheets("Info").Visible = True
    Sheets("Info").Activate
    report_month = Range("B5").Text
    report_year = Range("B4").Text
    Sheets("Report").Range("A1:AJ498").Copy
    Windows(filename).Activate
    Windows(report).Close
    Set newsheet = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count), Count:=1, Type:=xlWorksheet)
    report_name = (report_month & " " & report_year)
    newsheet.Name = (report_name)
    Sheets("Instructions").Range("C15").Value = (report_name)
    Sheets(report_name).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Instructions").Activate


End Sub
```

Comment: I see two problems. Your clipboard might be getting cleared. So move the copy statement before the paste statement. Also Please avoid the use of `.Select/.Activate` You may see [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179) If you are still stuck then please provide the following details and I can give you an example `1` Name of the workbook from where you are running the code. `2` Where do the sheets like "Info", "Report" etc reside? I mean which workbook?

Comment: `filename` holds the name of the current workbook. `report` holds the name of the workbook I am trying to copy from. `Info` is a hidden sheet in `report` which I am unhiding, `Report` is a worksheet inside `report` & `Instructions` is a worksheet inside `filename`.

Comment: One moment. posting an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I mentioned in my comments, you should avoid the use of `.Select/.Activate`. You may want to see [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/10718179#10718179)

If I change your code and use objects then your code may look like this.

Also move the copy code before the paste and include `DoEvents` between then so that Excel gets enough time to place the data onto the clipboard.

Try this

**UNTESTED**

```
Sub addsheet()
    Dim report_name As String
    Dim Filename As String, report_filepath As String, report As String
    Dim thisWb As Workbook, thatWb As Workbook
    Dim thatWs As Worksheet, NewSheet As Worksheet
    Dim report_month As String, report_year As String, report_name As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set thisWb = ThisWorkbook

    With thisWb
        Set NewSheet = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Worksheets.Count), Count:=1, Type:=xlWorksheet)
    End With

    report_filepath = "\\xxx\xxx\xxx\report.xlsx"

    Set thatWb = Workbooks.Open(report_filepath)
    Set thatWs = thatWb.Sheets("Info")

    With thatWs
        report_month = .Range("B5").Value
        report_year = .Range("B4").Value
    End With

    report_name = report_month & " " & report_year

    NewSheet.Name = report_name

    thisWb.Sheets("Instructions").Range("C15").Value = report_name

    thatWb.Sheets("Report").Range("A1:AJ498").Copy

    DoEvents

    NewSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                                      Operation:=xlNone, _
                                      SkipBlanks:=False, _
                                      Transpose:=False

    NewSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, _
                                      Operation:=xlNone, _
                                      SkipBlanks:=False, _
                                      Transpose:=False

    thisWb.Sheets("Instructions").Activate

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This runs :) However, I am still only getting the text copy and pasted, not the formatting.

Comment: I have edited the post above. Try it now. You may have to refresh the page :)

Comment: Perfect :) This works great, however, is there a way to copy and paste the whole sheets data contents? Including imbedded pictures and such?

Comment: Why do that not create a copy of the sheet instead?

Comment: @Keva161: See [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19584497/how-to-replicate-a-sheet-using-vba-macro-not-copy-replicate)

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to copy and paste the whole sheet. The sheet contains some formulas, so I only need the values.

Comment: Once you copy the sheet. Do a copy all cells and then paste values :)

Comment: you don't need a pastesepecial if you want to copy all (including comments, formating, pictures, validation...) : `thatWb.Sheets("Report").Range("A1:AJ498").Copy NewSheet.Range("A1")` .    So basicaly its just `A.copy B`, where A and B are ranges

Comment: PS: this method is said to not use the clipboard, thus faster and less problems...

Answer (score 0):

According to the Office help file, when you use the `Worksheet.PasteSpecial` method **"You must select the destination range before you use this method."**.

If you change

```
Sheets(report_name).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
```

to

```
Sheets(report_name).Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False
```

then it will work.

It would appear that the `.Paste` method will default to "A1" if no range is specified.

Further investigation shows that if you use `.PasteSpecial` without any parameters, i.e. `Sheets(report_name).PasteSpecial` then it will work without specifying a range. But if you include the parameters then it appears that you must specify the range

Comment: I am getting the error `Run-time error '1004' PasteSpecial method Range class failed`

Comment: Can you post your code? I tried this before answering, and it worked fine for me.